# SoapUI xPath match tests

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, soap, soapui

I'm writing some tests for my web service right now and can't find a lot of information regarding xPath match and Contains. Looking for examples as well.

1) For example, I would like to check if the date has format YYYY-MM-DD. 
Do i have to write regex expression in expected result?

http://prntscr.com/jhlxml

2) How can I check if answer equals to one of allowed values (using xsd enumeration)?
http://prntscr.com/jhm07g

Comment: Using images of your code makes it hard for others to reproduce your problem and help out. It's better to enter the text within the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the WSDL, those sorts of format and simple content validations can be built into the XML Schema within your WSDL that defines your response messages. Then, just use a Schema Compliance assertion on your test step.